# Interlacing Problems with Embedded Videos in Okular

Tags: multimedia, okular

I have a Dell Precision 5510 Laptop and I am having improper interlacing (horizontal lines) on the embedded videos in okular. Has anyone faced this problem before?

I am using the `multimedia` package. Here is a part-segment from my code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%% Preamble
\usepackage{multimedia}

%% in 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Introduction}

\movie[height = 0.55\textwidth, width = 1\textwidth, poster, showcontrols]{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{videos/math.png}}{videos/math.mp4}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Laptop details: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6820HQ CPU @ 2.70GHz 
Intel HD Graphics.
OS: Ubuntu 14.04
Okular version: 0.19.3

I am attaching two snapshots, one, where interlacing occurs (check right person)

[image: Interlacing problem] ,

and the other where the video still does not vanish and comes in the way of the next slide

[image: still image from video of previous slide].

Comment: In the MWE shouldn't the document class be `beamer` and `\begin{document}` on a new line (uncommented)? Without the actual movie you use or at least some data about it, it's hard to tell. On ubuntu 16.04 and okular 0.24.2 I tested some full hd movies I have around and there were no issues. The hardware specs are more than enough, no worries here.

Comment: I re-edited the question. I think the bot edited the question wrongly. I have tried with all videos, the horizontal lines are seen. If I use the externalviewer option, I dont see it happen. I am sure it has to do with the display drivers in my laptop. I don't get this problem in my desktop computer. Ubuntu,  okular, beamer versions are all the same.

Comment: I still have ubuntu 14.04 on another partition so I tried the pdf with okular 0.19.3. It complained about missing codecs and this is what can be wrong on your laptop:  wrong/buggy/old/unappropriate codecs that mess up the interlacing. Display driver is fine, don't worry about it.

Comment: I just realized that this occurs when running in vlc also. I guess it is a codec problem. It works fine in mplayer.

Now I am stuck with solving the interlacing problem of vlc player!!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by installing phonon-backend-vlc using the following command
       sudo apt-get install phonon-backend-vlc