# Embedding video in beamer using okular

Tags: pdftex, media9, multimedia, movie15

I've read everything on this topic like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163089/okular-to-play-embedded-videos-in-beamer), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158771/video-in-beamer-with-multimedia-package-not-playing), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317406/interlacing-problems-with-embedded-videos-in-okular), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427743/how-to-make-okular-play-embedded-video), etc.

All solutions are very old and I am not able to get them to work on my current system.

I am using:

- arch 4.19.4
- okular 1.5.3
- pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/Arch Linux)
- kpathsea version 6.3.0
- and I have installed the VLC phonen backend package phonon-qt5-vlc

Here is my minimal example .tex file:

```
\RequirePackage{flashmovie}
\documentclass[bookmarks=true]{beamer}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\begin{document}
Movie:
    \movie[
    height = 6cm,
    width = 6cm,
    showcontrols,
    poster
    ] 
    {}{./Circle-m-increase3.mp4}
\end{document}
```

Using the .mp4 supplied from this [example here](https://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/PDFmovie.html). I am producing the PDF using pdflatex. 
After 4 years, do we finally have a working solution to this problem on Linux?

Comment: I can play `avi` files with `okular`, using the `multimedia` package and after installing the `phonon-qt5-vlc` with pacman in arch.